# How do I abort or stop an http request in NodeJs

Tags: http, node.js, request-cancelling

While NodeJs architecture does very well to process server requests in a non-blocking way, it is sometimes required to stop/abort a request being processed at the server side.

How can I get my NodeJs server to abort a request even when it's not blocking the server?

Comment: Is this a outgoing or incoming request?

Comment: Hi Dan!
The request is coming into NodeJs from a C# client.

Comment: Can you just respond to a client with corresponding HTTP status code (500?) ?

Comment: Hi Andrew! Before the NodeJs server responds with 500 status code, it ideally has to stop the processing of the request first [say fetching of a file on the server]. If the server sends back response 500 before  it has actually stopped the fetching, it would still result into server resources being bogged down. Hope that explains.